# How can I solve this error: .exe file has stopped working

Tags: c++, matrix

I have 2x2 matrix. I want to check this matrix is symmetrical or not. When I add this function to my code, I am getting

> .exe file has stopped working error.

How can i fix this problem? Can someone help me?

```
void Array::symetrical_square_control()
{
        square2by2=new int*[4];
        int var2=0, var=0,i,k,l,j;

     for( i=0, l=var2 ;i<2 , l<var2+rowsize ;i++,l++) 
    {
        for( j=0 , k=var ; j<2, k<var+2 ;j++,k++) 
        {
            altkare2[i][j]=matris[l][k]; 
        }

        if(i==1) 
        {
            var++; 
            if(var==rowsize-1)
            {
                cout<<endl;
                for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
                {
                    cout<<endl;
                    for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
                    {
                        cout<<square2by2[x][y];

                    }
                }
                var = 0; 
                i-=2; 
                l-=1; 
                if(l==rowsize+1) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                i-=2; 
                l-=2; 
                cout<<endl;
                for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
                {
                    cout<<endl;
                    for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
                    {
                        cout<<square2by2[x][y];

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never create the arrays *inside* `square2by2`. They need to be initialized with `new` *separately*. When you do `cout<<square2by2[x][y];` there is no valid memory addess for the program to refer to, so you get a segmentation fault / access violation.

EDIT: to initialize `square2by2`:

```
square2by2 = new int* [2];
square2by2[0] = new int[2];
square2by2[1] = new int[2];
```

However, I don't see what you do with `square2by2` - you print its values *without* setting them to something first. I assume by `square2by2` you actually mean one of the other matrix variables (i.e. `altkare2` or `matris`)

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked.

Comment: @user5535577 nice. glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two obvious issues in the code, not sure if they fix everything but surely they should be fixed:

1)

> square2by2=new int*[4];

Here you just created an array of 4 pointers, not an array of 4 integers. And I dont see anywhere you put anything in this array, so its content is random, and later on, you reference it like this:

> cout << square2by2[x][y];

that is equivalent to `cout << *(square2by2[x] + y)`, with `square2by2[x]` being a non-initialized pointer, a random location, leading to crash.

2)

```
for( i=0, l=var2 ; i<2 , l<var2+rowsize ;i++,l++)
```

the stopping condition here is `l<var2+rowsize`, the first condition `i<2` has no effect. I am pretty sure this is not what you intend but something like && or ||, some combination of the two conditions.

Same apply to the other for:

```
for( j=0 , k=var ; j<2, k<var+2 ;j++,k++)
```

same here, `j<2` has no effect, but in this one it happens that the two conditions (separated by comma) are equivalent, so that luckily it wont lead to an error.